# What's going on in JavaScript when I use the "traditional" C-style function declaration?

Tags: javascript, function

I know that there are several ways to define a function in JavaScript. Two of the most common ones are:

```
(1)  function add (a, b) {
         return a + b;
     }

(2)  var add = function (a, b) {
         return a + b;
     }
```

I am comfortable with the idea of a function as an object that can be passed around just like any other variable. So I understand perfectly what `(2)` is doing. It's creating a function and assigning to `add` (let's say this is in the global scope, so `add` is a global variable) the said function. But then what is happening if I use `(1)` instead? I already know that it makes a difference in execution order: if I use `(1)` then I can refer to `add()` before the point in the code where `add()` is defined, but if I use `(2)` then I have to assign my function to `add` before I can start referring to `add()`.

Is `(1)` just a shortcut for `(2)`, albeit one that happens to behave like other C-style languages in allowing us to define a function "below" the point at which it's used? Or is it internally a different type of function? Which is more "in the spirit" of JavaScript (if that isn't too vague a term)? Would you restrict yourself to one or the other, and if so which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are already aware of the main characteristics of *[function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_declaration_(function_statement))*<sup>1</sup> (1) and *[function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_expression_(function_operator))* (2). Also note that in (1) there is still a local variable called `add` containing a function value, just like in (2):

```
function hello () {
   alert('Hello World');
}

console.log(typeof hello);  // prints "function"

setTimeout(hello, 1000);    // you can still pass functions around as arguments,
                            // even when using function declarations.
```

One other point worth mentioning is that *function declarations* (1) shouldn't be used to define functions conditionally (such as in `if` statements), because as you have mentioned, they are automatically moved to the top of the containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter<sup>2</sup>. This is normally referred to as *[hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)*.

As for which approach is more in the spirit of JavaScript, I prefer using *function expressions* (2). For a more authoritative opinion, [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) lists function declarations (1) in the "Bad Parts" chapter in his popular [The Good Parts book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Also known as *function statements* (See [@Tim Down's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) comments below).
<sup>2</sup> Actually some browsers are able to handle *function declarations* in `if` statements (Again refer to comments below).
<sup>3</sup> [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) - Appendix B: Page 113.

Comment: A function declaration within the block of an `if` statement is a syntax error, according to the ECMAScript spec. None of the major browsers throw an error, probably because of the precedent set by IE and Mozilla. Mozilla gets round it by including an extension to ECMAScript called a `FunctionStatement` (http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#functionStatement, http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements). JScript has less respect for the spec and does God-knows-what internally.

Comment: A comment on your edit: it is true that function declarations are also referred to as function statements, but incorrectly. The comp.lang.javascript FAQ (linked to in my previous comment) makes this point very eloquently: *"The term function statement has been widely and wrongly used to describe a `FunctionDeclaration`.This is misleading because in ECMAScript, a `FunctionDeclaration` is not a `Statement`; there are places in a program where a `Statement` is permitted but a `FunctionDeclaration` is not."*

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for the interesting comments. I wasn't aware of the "statement" naming issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo() {};
foo.toString() //-> "function foo() {}"

var bar = foo;
bar.toString() //-> "function foo() {}"
```

So it declares a named function.  No matter what variable points to it, it's name is retained.  Using the other syntax is an anonymous function, which is nameless and can only ever be accessed if referenced by a variable.

```
var foo = function() {};
foo.toString() //-> "function () {}"

var bar = foo;
bar.toString() //-> "function () {}"
```

As far as which style to use, there is no major rule.  Although I personally favor the anonymous syntax as it reminds me that functions are indeed objects that can be passed around.  I also tend to favor the "it's all in a big master object" approach, which requires that functions be declared this way.

```
var MyThingy = {
  foo: function() { alert('foo') },
  bar: function() { MyThingy.foo() }
}
```

But after the functions are created, the differences are not really important and behave the same.  But the anonymous syntax has less of that scan ahead magic you mentioned, and there less bugs in complex code and odd scoping situations.