# Precedence of function object expression in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, ecma262

In order to implement a tiny compiler that emits ECMAScript I need to know how strong a function object expression binds, i.e. what is the precedence of the "operator"
`function(a1, a2, ...) { ... }`?

For example, how is
`function(a1, a2, ...) { ... } (b1, b2, ...)`
supposed to be parsed? To get the wished for result, namely the application of b1, b2, ... to the function object, I have to use parentheses around the function object in the Rhino interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `function(a1, a2, ...) { ... } (b1, b2, ...)` is invalid, and should return a Syntax Error. ECMAScript has the concept of a `FunctionDeclaration` as well as that of a `FunctionExpression`. You may want to check out the following:

- [Function expressions vs. Function declarations](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl)
- [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/) ([@CMS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax/1634321#1634321))

While a `FunctionExpression` is an operator, the `FunctionDeclaration` is a special syntax used for declaring functions, which are automatically hoisted to the top of the enclosing scope.

Wrapping a `function` in the [grouping operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.6) (parenthesis) will force the interpreter to treat it as a `FunctionExpression`.

If you try the following in Firebug:

```
function () { alert('test'); }();       // Syntax Error
(function () { alert('test'); })();     // Works fine
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. (Actually to me it seems that this particular feature of ECMAScript hasn't been well thought of.)

Comment: @Marc: Yes, I agree. Function expressions should have been enough. There are many situations where function declarations are confusing in this language... This topic was recently discusses in another Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798984/whats-going-on-in-javascript-when-i-use-the-traditional-c-style-function-decla

Answer (score 0):

To execute a function literal, it needs to be enclosed in parentheses. Either:

```
(function(...){...})(...);
```

or:

```
(function(...){...}(...));
```

Without the parentheses it produces a syntax error.

Comment: It just has to be made into an r-value. Thus, `!funcion() { ... }` works too.